# Is it possible to get dynamic lease of IP address from LXD container on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: bridge, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, lxc, lxd

Followed “[Ubiquiti Networks UniFi Controller in an Ubuntu LXD Machine Container](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/12/unifi-controller-in-lxd.html)“ when setting up a new Ubuntu VM on Google Compute Engine.

But the container tries to lease an IP address, but nothing responds.  Is there some way to let the container lease from the 10.240.0.0/16 VPC network pool via the bridge to the host?

Comment: There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4952) that might help.

Comment: @Carlos IPAM and JessFraz is all cool stuff for docker, but not sure it applies to a lxd container.